# Represent Integer as sum of at least two consecutive postive Integers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

For the case that a natural number $N =c\cdot k$ where $c$ is odd, we can easily represent $N$ as following sum

$$N = \sum_{n = k - \frac{c-1}{2}}^{k + \frac{c-1}{2}} n$$

This covers all integers except for powers of two: $N=2^l$. Some experimenting suggests that we cannot decompose powers of two as sum of consecutive positive integers, but is there a way to prove this, or is there a counter example?

Comment: I'm glad you were able to figure it out on your own.  Your answer is absolutely correct.  It's frequently useful to consider power of 2s and numbers with an odd factor as the two classes of numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While writing the question, I came to following conclusion:

No it is not possible, observe following:

If $N= A+(A+1)+...+B$ then $$N=\frac{B(B+1)}{2}-\frac{A(A-1)}{2}$$

$$\iff 2N = B(B+1)-A(A-1) = (-A + B + 1) (A + B)$$

So if $N=2^l$ then $2^{l+1} = (-A+B+1)(A+B)$, so $A+B$ and $-A+B+1$ must both be powers of two. Obviously $B+A \equiv B-A \mod 2$, therefore $A+B \not \equiv B-A+1 \mod 2$, and therefore they can't both be powers of two (with a positive exponent). So this is only possible if one of the two is $1$, since. $A+B \geq B-A+1$ (for $A,B \geq 1)$ we have to have $A=B$, therefore there is no such representation.